# RestTemplate.exchange create Instance even if variable annotated @NotNull

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

So I have some class. Ex:

```
public class Operator {

    @NotNull
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private String operatorName;
}
```

And I want to get map of this objects with RestTemplate from another microservice

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Operator> operatorsMap(RestTemplate restTemplate, UriFactory uriFactory) {

    Map<String, Operator> map = Objects.requireNonNull(restTemplate.exchange(uriFactory.getOperatorsURI(),
            HttpMethod.GET,
            null,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Operator>>() {
            }).getBody());
    LOG.info("Successfully loaded data for {} operators", map.size());
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

Problem is - Even if id or operatorName comes with null from externalService, this restTemplate creates operator object and set this field to null. How can I prevent this behavior. The ideal behavior for me is exception and don`t start application.

Comment: I can avoid it by doing that     `public void setOperatorName(String operatorName) throws Exception {
        if (operatorName == null) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        this.operatorName = operatorName;
    }` But its not very beutifull

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be because the underlying json object mapper needs to be enforced during deserialization.

```
public class Operator {

    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    @Required
    @NotNull
    private Integer id;

    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    @Required
    @NotNull
    private String operatorName;

    Operator(@NotNull id, @NotNull operatorName) {
      this.id = id;
      this.operatorName = operatorName;
    }

}
```

Comment: Still null in field :-(

Comment: Can you try switching to `@Nonnull` annotation?

Comment: Thx for helping. But still same. Fields is null